# Audio Line is always unavailable

Tags: java, windows, audio

I have a problem with my code suddenly giving an error that it wasn't giving about 24hrs ago. No matter what input device I set as the default in Windows, I always get the following error:

> javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame not supported.at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:484)
> at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:115)
> at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:142)

Code for the recorder class:

```
public class SoundRecorder {
// record duration, in milliseconds
static final long RECORD_TIME = 60000;  // 1 minute

// path of the wav file
File wavFile = new File("Audio//RecordAudio.wav");

// format of audio file
AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

// the line from which audio data is captured
TargetDataLine line;

/**
 * Defines an audio format
 */
AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 8000;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
    int channels = 2;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = true;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
            channels, signed, bigEndian);
    return format;
}

/**
 * Captures the sound and record into a WAV file
 */
void start() {
    try {

        AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        System.out.println(format.properties());
        // checks if system supports the data line
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()));
            //System.out.println(line.getLineInfo());
            System.out.println("Line not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

        System.out.println(format.properties());
        //System.out.println(line.getLineInfo());

        //Error is here
        >>>line.open(format);

        System.out.println(format.properties());
        System.out.println(line.getLineInfo());
        line.start();   // start capturing

        System.out.println("Start capturing...");

        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

        System.out.println("Start recording...");

        // start recording
        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
 */
void finish() {
    line.stop();
    line.close();
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

}

Main:

```
SoundRecorder audio = new SoundRecorder();
    long recordTime = 60000L;
    Thread stopper = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(recordTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException var4) {
            var4.printStackTrace();
        }audio.finish();
    });
    stopper.start();
    System.out.println("stopper started");
    audio.start();
    System.out.println("audio started");
    stopper.join();}
```

I've tried restarting my computer, changing the encoding to signed, unsigned, float, alwa, and ulaw. I've tried changing the sample rate, size, and endian as well. I've also tried changing the default device from the audio mixer to the microphone as well.

Comment: Could you indicate the line in the code you wrote where the error occurs? I'd like to be able to better understand what executes and what doesn't, since you have some useful diagnostics built in. FWIW, my go-to format for audio (can count on it being supported) is "CD Quality Wav": 44100 fps, 16-bit, little endian, stereo. Also, maybe test your format with SourceDataLine or Clip, if you think the problem is the format?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner I've edited the code to show the error, but it occurs in the recorder class at "line.open(format);" I just now went back and adjusted to 44100fps, 16-bit, little endian and stereo but still no dice. I have a server side writer using SourceDataLine and will see if that can substitute.

Comment: That clarifies that the format is not the issue, since you test to check whether the line is supported prior to that error point. Is it possible that another application has recently started to monopolize the microphone? IDK if it would help to inspect the lines in your system, but if you want to try, the tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html has information that could help with inspecting the lines.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. For whatever reason all the permissions had been pulled from any app for microphone access. Once i turned on permissions, no more error. What's strange is that the Security Manager didn't catch it. I did some investigating in the DirectAudioDevice.java JRT file and found that even though it is supposed to check if the source is a TargetDataLine for recording permissions, it glossed right over it.

Comment: Glad to hear you got this sorted out! I recommend putting your solution in an "Answer" and selecting it as soon as you are permitted to do so. This will help others, and will also mean that people who are looking for questions to solve will know this has already been solved.